# Implementing a CMDB

Tags: configuration-management, cmdb

I have the need for an inventory for servers, storage, network devices, etc. and I'm thinking to have this kind of information in a CMDB.
It would first be used as an inventory, but later could be for configuration management as well.

Should I **create my own CMDB**, based on the KISS principle, and make it better over time ? **Or get a tool that already does the job**, but which I would not be able to evolve over time ?

Any experience with CMDB is welcome. I know that this is perhaps an opinion question, but I need to know what's best.

Comment: You missed a third option: "Get a tool that already does the job, AND being open source I can evolve over time".  Hint: They do exist.

Comment: And there are quite some.
1. Netbox
2. Ralph
3. i-doit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on how much time and money you have to throw at it.

---

[CMDBuild](https://www.cmdbuild.org/en/homepage): Open source (Hosted on [SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cmdbuild/))

[Device42](https://www.device42.com/device42-for-dcim/): DCIM/CMDB ([Has some opensource software](https://github.com/device42), no public pricing)

[Solarwinds CMDB](https://www.solarwinds.com/service-desk/use-cases/cmdb-software): $0.10/month per device + Agent Costs

[iTop](https://www.i-doit.org/): Open Source (Has Paid Version, Community is mainly in Dutch)

Service Now is another option but is an Enterprise Software.

---

I'd recommend looking online for reviews of the product, websites [like this](https://www.capterra.com/cmdb-software/) provide some good information, but use them as a grain of salt as far as the best products.

---

If you are looking for a SaaS product I'd look at IT Glue (although I wouldn't call it a CMDB), I have first-hand knowledge of it. It's not a bad product, it works well and has loads of integrations with popular RMM software to gather device information and has documentation capabilities for documents/procedures and a password vault etc.

Comment: Nice ones. CMDBuild seems interesting. 
I've found two that interest me and are quite full: i-doit and Ralph.

Comment: Hi @SamuelPE be sure to mark this as the answer if it completes your question.